# How to have a custom sort order for a union query in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, sql-order-by, union

With a query like this (simplified for clarity):

```
SELECT 'East' AS name, *
FROM events 
WHERE event_timestamp BETWEEN '2015-06-14 06:15:00' AND '2015-06-21 06:15:00' 

UNION

SELECT 'West' AS name, *
FROM events 
WHERE event_timestamp BETWEEN '2015-06-14 06:15:00' AND '2015-06-21 06:15:00'

UNION

SELECT 'Both' AS name, *
FROM events 
WHERE event_timestamp BETWEEN '2015-06-14 06:15:00' AND '2015-06-21 06:15:00'
```

I want to customise the order of the resulting rows. Something like:

```
ORDER BY name='East', name='West', name='Both'
```

Or

```
ORDER BY 
    CASE
        WHEN name='East' THEN 1 
        WHEN name='West' THEN 2
        WHEN name='Both' THEN 3
        ELSE 4
    END;
```

However, Postgres complains with:

```
ERROR:  invalid UNION/INTERSECT/EXCEPT ORDER BY clause
DETAIL:  Only result column names can be used, not expressions or functions.
HINT:  Add the expression/function to every SELECT, or move the UNION into a FROM clause.
```

Do I have any alternative?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Wrap it in a derived table (which is what "*HINT: .... or move the UNION into a FROM clause*" is suggesting)

```
select *
from (
  ... your union goes here ... 
) t
order by
    CASE
        WHEN name='East' THEN 1 
        WHEN name='West' THEN 2
        WHEN name='Both' THEN 3
        ELSE 4
    END;
```

Answer (score 17):

I'd add an extra column showing the desired ordering, then use ordinal column positions in the `ORDER BY`, e.g.

```
SELECT 1, 'East' AS name, *
...
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'West' AS name, *
...
ORDER BY 1
```

Note that you probably also want `UNION ALL` since your added columns ensure that every set in the union must be distinct anyway.

Comment: How would you use this inside a function that must only return a single value?

Comment: @pir Wrap it in an outer query that `SELECT`s just the value-column, using `FROM (SELECT ...)`

Answer (score 2):

By adding an extra column for ordering purpose, however it makes the UNION clause to work exactly as a UNION ALL (it does not eliminate duplicate rows from the result).

Comment: it is a great note, but it should be **a comment** on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31024172/1115187, not a new answer